# Multisite Upload URL?

Tags: multisite

I'm setting up a multisite at the moment but I'm experiencing some issues. I don't know if this is supposed to happen or if it's an error.

We are using Bedrock + Trellis for the setup and deployment. The child sites are set up using 'sub directories' with domain mapping (no plugin).

The problem is that the 'child sites' are serving images, css and js files from the 'Main domain' instead of the child site.

Like so:
https://example.com/app/uploads/**sites/7**/2018/11/image.png

Is there a way to resolve this somehow using a NGINX rewrite rule or similiar?

Update: The media files are working correctly. It complains about CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) though, but I think it's better to solve the main issue before configuring SSL.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. I think this is a good question. You might want to include some info in your question about whether the current image url results in a broken image as a result of the current path.